# $p-1$ divides ord($x$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $x$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. I have to prove that $p-1$ divides ord($x$) where $x\in\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. I had to prove the following results before this (in which I succeeded):
$(1+p)^{p^n}\equiv 1+p^{n+1}\text{ (mod }p^{n+2})$ and ord($1+p$)$=p^{n-1}$ where $1+p\in \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

I have been thinking alot about, but I cant figure it out. I really need hints! Thanks.

Comment: If $x$ is primitive root $\pmod p,\text{ord}_px=\phi(p)=p-1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I dont see why this is. Can you explain?

Comment: http://www.apfloat.org/prim.html. If the order of generator is $<p-1,$ it can not generate all the elements $\pmod p$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sorry, but I think I misunderstood you then, because I use the notation $ord_p(x)$ for how many factors $p$ $x$ has in his prime factorization. So how can I use it?

Comment: but $(x,p)=1$ and in my knowledge ord$_px=d$ means $d$ is the smallest positive integer such that $x^d\equiv1\pmod p$

Comment: @Badshah If that is your definition of ord, then there is absolutely no way you could have proved $\text{ord}(1+p) = p^{n-1}$ as you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not need much machinery for the proof.  Let $d$ be the order of $x$ modulo $p^n$. Then in particular $x^d \equiv 1\pmod{p^n}$.

It follows that $x^d\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Thus the order of $x$ modulo $p$ divides $d$. This order is $p-1$.